# Как реализовать перезагрузку 4g USB модем без физического извлекания из порта USB

Tags: windows, usb, модемы, at

USB 4g модем yota воткнут напрямую в USB порт, система Windows 7.

Цель - сделать перезагрузку модема, чтобы поменялся ip адрес.
Если физически вытащить и вставить модем, то ip меняется.

Попробовал сделать:

devcon disable/enable *VID_1376*

Интернет выключается/включается, однако индикатор работы модема не гаснет (диод на корпусе модема) и ip не меняется. Возможно нужно отключить питание на модеме?

Также прочитал, что существуют AT команды для управления модемом, но вся информация о них представлена для huawei, zte модемов.
Какие есть варианты? Может кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо определиться с реальным названием модели модема/маршрутизатора. В большинстве случаев это как правило Huawei. Далее вам необходимо посетить форумы по разблокировке данного аппарата. Например, сойдёт 4pda.ru для этих целей.

После изучения методов разблокировок вы узнаете как именно происходит подключение к устройству - через HTTP запрос для перевода его Debug режим или сразу прямое общение через SSH терминал.

Там же, как правило присутствует набор AT команд для некоторых функций. Возможно, вам повезёт и вы в последовательностях команд для смены IMEI или иных данных найдёте заветную. А именно - команду RESET, которая перегружает устройство. Например, для маршрутизатора (уже не модем) Huawei e8273h эта команда выглядит как `AT^RESET`. Но перед её вызовом придётся перевести устройство в debug режим отправив XML запрос по HTTP протоколу на URL маршрутизатора (например пусть будет http://192.168.8.1/cgi). Потом можно смело подключаться к появившемуся в системе COM порту и отправлять AT команды по SSH протоколу.

В принципе ничего сложного тут нет. Важно знать последовательность действий и после описать их программно, чтобы получить программу с одной лишь кнопкой для перезагрузки подключенного модема/маршрутизатора.

P.S. Тут мной описан был самый тяжёлый случай. У многих модемом COM порт терминала активен по умолчанию. Важно узнать команду перезагрузки устройства. Естественно нет смысла искать более специфичные команды, которые могут управлять функциями связи, т.к. вряд ли это доступно для широкой публики.

Comment: Модель модема YOTA 4G LTE WLTUBA-115, насколько понимаю, это всё же не Huawei.